# Unicode encoding in email

Tags: python, unicode, unicode-string

I have manually created and sent myself an html email in gmail. I want to be able to reuse this html output to programatically send it (using smtplib in python).

In gmail, I view the source, which appears like:

> Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>   boundary="--==_mimepart_57daadsdas2e101427152ee"; charset=UTF-8
>   ----==_mimepart_57daadsdas2e101427152ee Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
>
> **Hi all !**
>   =3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D=3D
>
> Venez d=C3=A9couvrir

My problem is that when I then try to send this content as html programatically, it's not displayed correctly. I suspect it's because of unicode conversion. I can't convert back for example the characters "d=C3=A9couvrir" to what it should be: "découvrir".

Could anyone help?

Comment: Those 2 hex codes are indeed the correct UTF8 representation of `e acute`, so the problem lies elsewhere. Where is your code that sends it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's are some [MIME examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html#email-examples) that are probably more suitable, but the simple answer from the headers is that it is UTF8 and `quoted-printable` encoding, so you can use the `quopri` module:

```
>>> quopri.decodestring('Venez d=C3=A9couvrir').decode('utf8')
'Venez découvrir'
```